# Excel wont delete content from a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Sorry if this has already been asked. I looked but couldn't see a post on it already.

I don't know what I did, but somehow I ended up editing a cell that simply said:

> Gulfstream 650

so that it now says:

> =3:87Gulfstream 650

Now it won't let me:

- Delete the text from that cell
- Delete that row or column
- Undo
- Close
- Add text to that cell (for example the apostrophe that stops formulas
  from calculating)

When I try some actions (hitting enter, close or save) it comes up with this error message:

[image: error message]

Clicking help does nothing.

When I try to cut, delete, paste, change the text absolutely nothing happens.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Apparently I'm running file version 16.0.71167.2040 and Microsoft Office 2016.
I'm running Windows.

Comment: Is the file a macro enabled file (*.xlsm)?  If so, there may be a macro running that is preventing you from changing the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in formula edit mode, Excel checks the formula when you leave the cell you are editing. You are getting the error because of the typo and it is not a valid formula.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click the `X` to the left of the formula bar to cancel the changes.

[image]

If it won't let you do that, delete the `=3:87` prior to the text.

Answer (score 2):

Try just `ESC` to cancel the formula changes.